# Display second image when the 1'st image was selected

Tags: php, mysql

I have a list with images which I display from db like this:

```
<?php                                           
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM images ORDER BY position");
    while ($image = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
?>
        <img src="/<?php echo $image['thumb'];?>" />
    
php } ?>
```

I already created a mask where to display the big image but I have no idea how do I know which image is clicked then to display the big image inside the popup.

Fields I use from db are

```
image_id    
image   
position    
thumb
```

Comment: Hi BloodRayne, can you give us some more details? Are you using Javascript to display the big image? You would normally wrap the thumbnail with a link which calls a Javascript function to display the selected image.

Comment: Yes that's correct <a href="#dialog"  name="modal"  class="info">More </a>       http://jsfiddle.net/U3pfQ/

Comment: If English is your first language I'm -1 this.

Comment: No english is my second i'm romanian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to surround your `<img>` tag with a `<a>` link that points to another PHP script which retrieves the correct image:

#### Inside your while() loop:

```
<a href='getImage.php?id=<?php echo $image['image_id']; ?>'>
  <img src="/<?php echo $image['thumb'];?>" />
</a>
```

#### getImage.php

`getImage.php` mainly displays an `<img>` tag containing the full size image selected earlier. Be sure to fill in the rest of the HTML it needs as necessary, as I have only included the `<img>` tag below.

```
$img = isset($_GET['id']) ? intval($_GET['id']) : NULL;

if ($img) { 
  $image_qry = mysql_query("SELECT image FROM images WHERE image_id = $img");
  if ($image_qry) {
    $image_data = mysql_fetch_assoc($image_qry);
    // One row was returned...
    if ($image_data) {
      echo "<img src='{$image_data['image']}' alt='alt text...' />";
    }
  }
}
else {
  // Invalid id, not an integer
}
```

Comment: If the data in the image column is a filename, you could point your link directly to the big file without having to do a second SQL query.

Comment: ok so i tryed liked this                                        <a href='#dialog?id=<?php echo $image['image_id']; ?>' name="modal">  and i  set the else to return an error in case of nothing and ofc  ghet the error . I don't wanna go to another page :(    Want me to upload it to a serv and see ?

Comment: Ok after me beeing a newb i finaly figured out what u rly wanted to say. Worked like a charm

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php                                           
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM images ORDER BY position");
    while ($image = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
?>
        <img src="/<?php echo $image['thumb'];?>"  onclick="openImage('<?php echo $image["image"];?>');" />

<?php } ?>
```

than write a javascript function called `openImage(image_src)` that will put the image in the right location

Answer (score 0):

Look at this and pick something that satisfy your needs http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/css/fresh-jquery-image-gallery-display-solutions/

Comment: Unfortunatly i am not looking for an image gallery :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
  function showBigImage(image_id){
     // show your big image here with using image_id
  }
</script>
<?php                                           
  $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM images ORDER BY position");
  while ($image = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
?>
    <img src="/<?php echo $image['thumb']; ?>" onclick="showBigImage('<?php echo $image["image_id"]; ?>');" />

<?php } ?>
```